# Selenium Report generating in Specflow using c#

Tags: c#, extentreports

I have created a code for extent report generation which I have mentioned in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEmdP.png). The code is working fine but my doubt is:

```
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void initializwHtmlReport()
        {

        string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHMMss");
        var htmlreporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"C:\Users\ffaiyazf\Downloads\Selenium-Webdriver (1)\TestResults\"+ name +".html");
        htmlreporter.Config.Theme = AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter.Configuration.Theme.Standard;
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlreporter);

        }

        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void teardownreport()
        {
            extent.Flush();
        }
```

It has created two files with name as index.html and dashboard.html. If you see the code again I didn't mention that names `index` and `dashboard` how to generate a report as my own name. Could you please help me to resolve the issue.

And also I have attached the image of that [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDr0f.png) created. I didn't mention those names in my code but it was showing those names.

Answer (score 1):

> What you are seeing is the new default Html reporter for version 4. This defaults to 4 templates: index.html, dashboard.html, tag.html and exception.html. Because each view is broken-down to its own file, we can ensure the overall responsive is much better than version 3. If you would like to use the old reporter, use ExtentV3HtmlReporter.

From: https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-csharp/issues/7

Meaning, you can downgrade to version 3 of the [ExtentReports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtentReports/3.1.3) NuGet package to avoid the default HTML view files naming.

Comment: @faiyaz f 
Please mark V on my answer as I think it helps solve your problems.